# SAS EG Transpose step is adding a bunch of spaces to my data. Can I prevent this?

Tags: sas, transpose, enterprise-guide

I inherited a run that has a Transpose step in SAS EG. The data has a column with values reading NOV2020,SEP2019 etc., and a name column with Firstname Lastname.

When transposed, these columns merge into a single Character column. The name values remain the same, but now the dates read like ‘_________NOV2020’ (no underscores, just spaces) instead of just ‘NOV2020’.

Is there something in the Transpose step in SAS EG that can be modified to prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are transposing character and numeric variables.  Did you notice a message in the log about numeric to character conversion.

Most numeric formats default to right justification. The length of the new character variable is defined as the max of the (character var lengths, formatted width of numeric vars)

You can "correct" with the LEFT function.